# Android Hilt injecting interface to a viewmodel impelemented by an activity

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

New to DI, Using Hilt I'm trying to inject an interface implemented by an activty to a viewmodel like this:

Activity class:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity  : AppCompatActivity(), AnInterface{
    private val mainViewModel : MainViewModel by viewModels()
    // .....
}
```

ViewModel :

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() @Inject constructor(anInterface : AnInterface){

}
```

Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class ActivityModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideAnInterface(activity: Activity) : AnInterface = activty as AnInterface

}
```

Gives me error :

```
AnInterface cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

Comment: did you solve the problem? There are still some cases that we need interface implemented by activity context. It could be some separate logic, and routing in that interface right

Comment: @Steven.Nguyen Did you get any solution?

Comment: @Rakesh. Unfortunately, I haven't found solutions, but it works on version - 2.28.3-alpha for Hilt. I believe that someone will get the same problems like this. Google suggest to use Live Data to interact between viewModel and UI. But obviously, it doesn't work on all cases right. If we can use Interface in ViewModel, it's better

Comment: @Louell Have you solve the prolem?

Answer (score 2):

You should not pass Activity's reference to `ViewModel` That clearly violates the loose coupling feature of MVVM.  Dependency flows inwards in MVVM.
Use `LiveData` instead to observe the Data from `ViewModel` in Activity/Fragment do not use an Interface.

[image]